# how to disable autostart of Oracle 11gR2 on ubuntu 16.04 when i start my computer?

Tags: database, oracle, ubuntu-16.04, oracle11gr2

I installed oracle database with the help of this : How to install Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu 14.04? my problem is that oracle start automatically in the start of the pc I want to disable the autostart of orcaledatabase and start it only manually

Answer (score 0):

If the setup is using the preferred way to start/stop (dbstart/dbshut) then there should be a file **/etc/oratab** that lists your database. In the end of the line there is a "Y" which stands for **Yes** in autostart.

Change that to **N**, if that doesn't work, you are using non-(oracle)standard way to run the DB.

Run **initctl list** and look for anything relating to Oracle. (or **service --status-all** )

Comment: for the first solution I founded in the end of the line N so i'm using non-(oracle)standard way to run the DB
when I run initctl list it gives me :initctl: Name "com.ubuntu.Upstart" does not exist
i runed upstart and i found  :
oracle-xe.service           loaded active exited    LSB: Oracle 11g Express Edit